categorize repos in gitweb by subdirectories
With cgit I can set configuration variable section-from-path, and it makes all repos be grouped under their directories like at https://git.cepl.eu/cgit/. Unfortunately, I cannot find the equivalent for the plain gitweb, so https://git.cepl.eu/git/ looks convoluted.
Any idea, how to achieve the same effect with gitweb?
